# can you change the side of the dropdown button in a select element

Tags: javascript, css, sass

quick question, how can I change the default dropdown button of a select element from right to left, I've been trying to do this for an i18n services for Right-to-Left script languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `dir="rtl"` hope this will help you
https://jsfiddle.net/fparent/YSJU7/